# Transform a variable's exponent from an exact rational to an inexact decimal

Tags: functions, numerics

here is a little problem I could not find a solution for.

I have a variable with an exponent represented as a fraction, for example,

```
var = a^(39/106)
```

Now I would like to have *Mathematica* report this as a decimal fraction, like

```
var = a^0.368
```

Is there a way to do it in functional style, something like NExponentsAsDecimals[var]? I want to apply this to results obtained from `Solve` etc.

Comment: Try N[#] & /@ var

Comment: or just `N /@ var`

Comment: or var /. z1_^z2_ :> z1^N[z2].  Lots of ways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Mike Honeychurch suggested

```
var = N /@ var
```

> `a^0.367925`

is probably the simplest way to do what you ask for.